# reference when rewriting an URL

Tags: css, .htaccess, easyphp

I'd like to transform an URL like this 
http://www.mydomain.com/it/archive.php=321123
in one like the following
http://www.mydomain.com/it/R/321123
In a book I found something useful with few practice I get the following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^R/(.*) archive.php?$1 [PT]
```

which work properly.
The problem is that any ref inside of the code like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css" />
```

is trasnformed into

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="www.mydomain.com/it/R/css/layout.css" />
```

The R folder does't exist in the reality so it doesn't contain any css file, all the css files are stored into the folder http://www.mydoman.com/it/css.
The Chrome developers utility give me the following:
*Resouce interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.mydomain.com/it/R/css/style.css".*

Is possibile to change the address but mantain the same references of the original page inside of the page. I could write

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.mydomain.com/it/css/layout.css" />
```

but this should not work when I am working offline with EasyPHP.

PS: I'd like to put the .htaccess file into the http://www.mydomain.com/it folder so it will affect only the it language part.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this to the header of the pages:

```
<base href="/it/">
```

And that should make it so the *relative* URI paths (e.g. "css/layout.css") don't get mixed up with the `/R/` from the rewriting.

If that's not possible, you could try adding extra rules to make the css work:

```
RewriteRule ^R/css/(.*)$ css/$1 [L]
```

Comment: The extra rule down't make any imporvement but the <base href="/it/">
work great! The problem now is that the page doesn't get the variable. Open http://www.mydomain.com/it/R/321123 is like open http://www.mydomain.com/it/archive.php without variable.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that your rules were probably based in /it/, try my edited RewriteRule, in the same place that your archive.php rule is.

Comment: OK, I fixed it. The problem was that I did't wrote the name of the variable (ID). The correct code is RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^R/(.*) archive.php?ID=$1 [PT]

Comment: Neither the edited version works. Don't mind, I think the <base href="/it/"> code is much better, as it works with css, images, js ... and any other ref inside the page! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the part after the R/ is always numbers, try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^R/([0-9]*) archive.php?$1 [PT]
```

Comment: The issue isn't that the `RewriteRule` is being applied to the css link, it's because the link is a relative path and the browser's URI is `/it/R/` so the "css/layout.css" just gets appended to the end of that.